# Android. Interact with menu from Presenter

Tags: android, mvp, gwtp

Can't understand how can i manipulate with menu from Presenter. For example i have some rules to add menu item (for example ROLE), or i want to update text of menu item (badge) from background. I know that i can do all things in Activity, but Activity is a View. 
So, if follow MVP rules, all things which communicate with db, services and etc must be do in presenter, but as i right understood, state of menu item can be change only in

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) {}
```

P.S. Only one thought comes to mind. Is call method in presenter on `

```
SomeView.onCreateOptionsMenu()
```

But i don't want set Menu in presenter

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How update state of menu item from Presenter.

Comment: You can save a reference to the `Menu` or a `MenuItem` in your Activity, and at some point your Presenter can tell your Activity that it needs to change something about them. Honestly though, I think people make their lives harder for themselves trying to enforce these MVC/MVP/MVVM architectures on top of Android. Granted that's an opinionated statement, I just haven't experienced any significant benefit to shoehorning these paradigms into Android.

Comment: I'm using MVP in Vaadin, GWT. So it's very close to me. If save a reference in Activity is a legal way, so it's ok. Thanks alot ;)

Comment: As "Karakuri" has already told, You can have your own methods in view to manipulate  the menu as you let your presenter know when you want to do and then calling these methods from presenter.
Personally I feel mvp helps a lot in keeping to code clean and enhanceable.

Comment: Yes, MVP rly helps to contain code clean, sure if you understand it right.

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.